# how toget x and y cooridinates of sprit2 when sprite1 collides with it in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

how to get x and y coordinates of sprit2 when sprite1 collides with it i use collision update handler. my requirement is when sprite 1 collide with sprite2 it attach with sprite2 on that point where it collides?
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some more details at present doesn't able to understand your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the Box2D extension for andengine. you basically attach physics bodies to sprites. then you use a contact listener to take care of collision events. here is how you would get the contact points of the collision in the listener...

```
protected ContactListener createContactListener() {
    return new ContactListener() {
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
            Vector2[] contactPoints = contact.getWorldManifold().getPoints();
             for(int i = 0; i < contactPoints.length; i++) {
                 ...
             }
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate on How to get the contact points. I am not getting contact points with the code you gave.